# Slackbuild script with "set -e" exit..at no error!

Tags: scripting, error-handling, exit-status, slackware, slackbuilds

With this slackbuild:

```
#!/bin/sh

PRGNAM=libnfsidmap
VERSION=${VERSION:-0.25}
BUILD=${BUILD:-3}
TAG=${TAG:-_mg}

if [ -z "$ARCH" ]; then
  case "$( uname -m )" in
        i?86) ARCH=i486 ;;
        arm*) ARCH=arm ;;
           *) ARCH=$( uname -m ) ;;
  esac
fi


CWD=$(pwd)
TMP=${TMP:-/tmp/txz}
PKG=$TMP/package-$PRGNAM
OUTPUT=${OUTPUT:-/tmp}

if [ "$ARCH" = "i486" ]; then
  SLKCFLAGS="-O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686"
  LIBDIRSUFFIX=""
elif [ "$ARCH" = "i686" ]; then
  SLKCFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686 -mtune=i686"
  LIBDIRSUFFIX=""
elif [ "$ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then
  SLKCFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC"
  LIBDIRSUFFIX="64"
fi

set -e

SOURCE="http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/libnfsidmap/libnfsidmap-$VERSION.tar.gz"

if [ ! -e $PRGNAM-$VERSION.tar.gz ];
then
    wget -c $SOURCE
else
    echo "already download"
fi


rm -rf $PKG
mkdir -p $TMP $PKG $OUTPUT
cd $TMP
rm -rf $PRGNAM-$VERSION
tar xzvf $CWD/$PRGNAM-$VERSION.tar.gz
cd $PRGNAM-$VERSION

CFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
CXXFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr \
  --libdir=/usr/lib${LIBDIRSUFFIX} \
  --sysconfdir=/etc \
  --localstatedir=/var \
  --mandir=/usr/man \
  --build=$ARCH-slackware-linux

make
make install DESTDIR=$PKG
mkdir $PKG/etc
install -m 644 $CWD/idmapd.conf $PKG/etc

( cd $PKG
  find . | xargs file | grep "executable" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null || true
  find . | xargs file | grep "shared object" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null
)

( cd $PKG/usr/man
  find . -type f -exec gzip -9 {} \;
  for i in $( find . -type l ) ; do ln -s $( readlink $i ).gz $i.gz ; rm $i ; done
)

mkdir -p $PKG/usr/doc/$PRGNAM-$VERSION
cp -a \
  $TMP/$PRGNAM-$VERSION/README $TMP/$PRGNAM-$VERSION/AUTHORS $TMP/$PRGNAM-$VERSION/COPYING \
    $PKG/usr/doc/$PRGNAM-$VERSION
cat $CWD/$PRGNAM.SlackBuild > $PKG/usr/doc/$PRGNAM-$VERSION/$PRGNAM.SlackBuild
chown -R root:root $PKG/usr/doc
find $PKG/usr/doc -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

mkdir -p $PKG/install
cat $CWD/slack-desc > $PKG/install/slack-desc

cd $PKG
/sbin/makepkg -l y -c n $CWD/$PRGNAM-$VERSION-$ARCH-$BUILD$TAG.txz
```

I compile with

```
sudo sh *ld
```

and...it exit after the make even with no errors(!)
after the line

```
make install DESTDIR=$PKG
```

If I remove set -e,continue and create my package correctly.
Why is exiting with set -e? As I know set -e mean "exit from script if error happen".
Distro is slackware 14.2,bash is 4.3.48,I try also bash script.sh..but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found
The incriminated lines are..

```
( cd $PKG
  find . | xargs file | grep "executable" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null || true
  find . | xargs file | grep "shared object" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null
)
```

Even if no error happen (and in this case is hidden by the 2>) if not strip is needed or file missing, the script return not 0 status and exit (set -e).
With this correction

```
( cd $PKG
  find . | xargs file | grep "executable" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null || true
  find . | xargs file | grep "shared object" | grep ELF | cut -f 1 -d : | \
    xargs strip --strip-unneeded 2> /dev/null || true
)
```

All works fine.

So I missed a `|| true` in the latest strip line.